# OCaml variable shadowing?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

If I have a nested function like such

```
let test1 (sorted: int list) =
let test2 (sorted: int list) =
{blah with sorted} in
test2 sorted
```

How does the shadowing work? Inside test2 I'll use the parameter passed in (sorted) or will it access the larger scope sorted declared in test1?

Answer (score 1):

When there are multiple variables in scope with the same name, you will always access the one from the inner-most scope. So on line 3 you're accessing the parameter of `test2` and on line 4 you're accessing the parameter of `test1`.